# Show all errors for user after form submit in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form. If something is wrong then error message is shown. Currently it is only showing one error message, even though I am pushing the error messages into an array in PHP and json encoding the array.

What I would basically like to do is this:

```
$errors = []; // Array creation
if (strlen($username) < 5) { 
    // Add this error to our list
    $errors[] = 'Username not valid.';
} 

if ($password != $passwordRetype) {
    // Add this error to our list
    $errors[] = 'Password does not match our records.';
}

// Repeat this process for other errors
// Then handle your list of errors
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo "Error Found: $error<br>";
}
```

but only in `ajax` and `php`.

Currently I have this (a lot of code so skipping some parts):

```
 $.ajax({
     url: $form.attr('action'),
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         if (data.status == 'success') {
          console.log("success");
         } else if (data.status == 'not_image') {
          console.log("this is not an image");
         } else if (data.status == 'image_exists') {
          console.log("this image exists");
         }
     });
 });
```

This is the PHP

```
$errors_query = array();

            if (!empty($images)) {
                $uploadOk = 0;
                $errors++; 
                $errors_query["status"] = 'image_exists';


            }elseif(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)){
                $uploadOk = 0;
                $errors++; 
                $errors_query["status"] = 'not_image';

            }else{
                $uploadOk = 1;
                $errors_query["status"] = 'success';

            }
    if($errors > 0){
        echo json_encode($errors_query);
        exit();
    }else{
        echo json_encode($errors_query);
        exit();
    }
```

It works and shows only one response message, even if both data statuses "image_exists" and "not_image" are present. How can I show all the error messages for the user?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

Just do like this

PHP Code

```
       $errors_query = array();


        if (!empty($images)) {

            $errors_query['msg'][] = 'Sorry Image not exists';
            $errors_query['status'] = FALSE;


        } elseif (!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {

            $errors_query['msg'][] = 'not_image';
            $errors_query['msg'][] = 'msg2';
            $errors_query['msg'][] = 'msg3';
            $errors_query['status'] = FALSE;

        } else {

            $errors_query['msg'][] = 'success';
            $errors_query['status'] = TRUE;

        }


         echo json_encode($errors_query);
```

jQuery Code

```
 $.ajax({
             url: 'http://localhost/welcome/raja',
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             type: 'GET',
             success: function(data) {
             var data = JSON.parse(data);
                 if (data.status === true) {

                  console.log("success");

                 } else {

                $.each(data.msg, function( index, value ) {
              console.log( index + ": " + value );
               });


                 }
             },
         });
```

It is working example i have already tested .Happy Work ............ :)

Comment: so when Implementing this I still get only the last error show, so "not_image".

Comment: So in the console it shows me array[1] even though it should display [2] since I have to errors.

Answer (score 0):

What I roughly understood (correct me if I'm wrong) is that

1. Your PHP code creates an array for errors and loops through some if-else statements to check for errors for the uploaded file and add the errors to the array under the key "status"
2. Encode into JSON and pass it to your AJAX code
3. Your AJAX code will then return the error message based on the return JSON

I found some problems with your code:

1. When you use if-else for your error checking in your PHP file, **once the first error has been logged, the other errors will not be checked**. This is because as the first *if* has been accessed, the subsequent *if-else* and *else* statements will be skipped. Hence, if the file is determined to exist, your code will not check if it's not an image.
2. The AJAX has the same fundamental problem as point 1. Once one error has been printed, it will not print out the rest, **hence your issue of only showing 1 error message**.
3. If you use the same key in the array, the **older errors will be overwritten by the new ones**.

To rectify, you can do the following:

1. Add each error message as an individual element in an subarray of your original array, such as *$errors_query[errors][]*. This will allow you to use the other elements - like *$errors_query[status]* - to populate your status. Take a look at the [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function on how to add an element to the end of an array. The plus of such method is you don't have to worry how many error messages you'll have - just keeping adding to the end of the array.
2. Your AJAX code should then loop through the subarray that you have created in step 1 ("errors" here) and print them out accordingly.

Unfortunately I don't have a production software in the computer I'm using now, so I can't write a working code for you to copy, but hopefully this allows you to approach a direction.

Comment: you got the idea indeed and thanks for the input. how should I create the if else statements then?

Comment: Something along the line of this http://textuploader.com/5i8d0. I'm unable to test if it really works for now as I'm typing from memory, nor can I test how your AJAX should change accordingly.

Comment: Oh dear I missed something out. In the last else statement - **else if($errors == 0)** - do include the returning of the JSON too: **echo json_encode($errors_query);**. My apologies for leaving it out.

Comment: So I tried it and it gives me this Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given.

Comment: It's because **$errors_query["message"] is not created and hence doesn't exist (is null)**. You can create it by including these at the top when initialising your variables: http://textuploader.com/5i8dm. The "status" initialisation is not really necessary, but you can add it in for standardisation.

Comment: So I changed it and it still shows me only the last error.

Comment: It's because you will need to change your AJAX too - in case you did not. If you have the time, I can create a working copy when I get home as I am at work and my computer doesn't have such software. Meanwhile, you can take a look at and try out the other answers =)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Your ajax jquery code has some problem,You included extra " ); " in the closing of success function part.

```
$.ajax({
     url: $form.attr('action'),
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         if (data.status == 'success') {
          console.log("success");
         } else if (data.status == 'not_image') {
          console.log("this is not an image");
         } else if (data.status == 'image_exists') {
          console.log("this image exists");
         }
     });
 });
```

If you check the result in the browser console,then you can see mentioned JavaScript error.

```
$.ajax({
             url: $form.attr('action'),
             data: formData,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             type: 'POST',
             dataType :"json",
             success: function(data) {
                 console.log(data.status);
                 var ajaxResult = data.status;
                 if (ajaxResult.indexOf("success") != -1) {
                  console.log("success");
                }
                if (ajaxResult.indexOf("not_image") != -1 ) {
                  console.log("this is not an image");
                }
                if (ajaxResult.indexOf("image_exists") != -1) {
                  console.log("this image exists");
                 }
             }
         });
```

PHP code is below.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/json; charset=UTF-8");
$errors_query = array();
$flag1 =0 ;
$allowed = array("png","jpg","jpeg"); // Give the correct values based on your requirement
$images=""; // Assign the correct value based on your program
$file_type= ""; // Assign the correct value
$errors=0;

if (!empty($images)) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
    $errors++;
    $errors_query["status"][] = 'image_exists';
  $flag1 =1;
}

if (!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
    $errors++;
    $errors_query["status"][] = 'not_image';
  $flag1 =1;
}

if($flag1 == 0 ) {
    $uploadOk               = 1;
    $errors_query["status"][] = 'success';

}
if ($errors > 0) {
    echo json_encode($errors_query);
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode($errors_query);
    exit();
}
?>
```